# Why don't the Target 8 files implement the project as described in the tutorial?

Tags: dom, element, dart, dart-webui, dart-editor

In [Target 8: Define a Custom DOM Tag](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/custom-elements/), the reader is told about custom DOM tags that can be created by extending other tags.  A sample is described for an example called "x-converter" before listing the files as "These files implement the app:".

The three files are...

- a [drseuss.html](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples/blob/master/web/target08/drseuss/web/drseuss.html) file (not sure why there's a sudden deviation in the project name and the HTML file, as opposed to the matching names in previous tutorials...),
- a [converter-element.html](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples/blob/master/web/target08/drseuss/web/converter-element.html) file,
- and a [convertercomponent.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples/blob/master/web/target08/drseuss/web/convertercomponent.dart) file.

I tried creating a new application in the latest Dart editor, and replaced the default HTML file contents with that of drseuss.html, replaced the default dart file contents with that of convertercomponent.dart, and added converter-element.html file.

After fixing an include issue (the file from the tutorial refers to drseuss.css and not the default project name's CSS file), I only see the following in the Chromium browser.

[image: No element as shown in the tutorial!]

As you can see, the element described in the tutorial (converter-element) doesn't show up.  **Why don't the files provided for the project result in what's shown in the tutorial?**

For reference, here's what's shown in the tutorial.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the report, we're tracking here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web UI requires the `build.dart` script which compiles the various components into the executable output HTML+Dart.

Take a look at the [parent folder](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples/tree/master/web/target08/drseuss) in the github src that you reference, and you will see the `build.dart` script.

In addition, you will need the `pubspec.yaml` from that folder, too, which includes `web_ui` package, which brings in the dwc tool(Dart Web Components compiler) used by `build.dart`.

Take a look at the article [Tools for Web UI](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/tools.html) for more information about dwc and build.dart, and [Target 6 - Getting Started with Web UI](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/web-ui/) which covers similar ground, but in a tutorial format.

Comment: I haven't revisited this, but since someone else upvoted you I'll assume that they've tried and appreciated your input.